# Multiple Static methods

Tags: java, static-methods

I have declared three static methods in my java program, apart from the main()

method. Since a static method is executed first when a program is run, which

method will be executed first? Will it be one of the static methods that I have

declared, or will it be the main method?

Comment: *Since a static method is executed first when a program is run* <= No, static methods are not magically executed when a program is run and that makes the rest of the question irrelevant. Did you mean static fields? Always try to provide example code with a question like this. Otherwise it leads to guesswork answers.

Comment: Are you speaking about static methods or static blocks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `main` method will be executed first, unless you explicitly execute one of the other static methods in a static initializer block or in the initialization of a static variable.

For example, here's a scenario in which static methods (`method1` and `method2`) are executed before the `main` method :

```
public class SomeClass
{
    static int v = method2 ();

    static {
        method1 ();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

    }

    public static void method1 ()
    {

    }

    public static int method2 ()
    {
        return 5;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods you write are, in general, not executed without being called.

Main you call by executing your program.

Answer (score 0):

It will be always static when it comes to execution
then it will go for Main method
Reason behind is static method it store in memory